# "?:" character combination in python regex

Tags: python, regex

What does `?:` mean when using 'or' in python regex?

e.g

`(?:^|\n)` does capture the match in say following text

```
sample text sample text\nsample text sample text
```

but `(^|\n)` does not.

What is a reason for that?

Comment: `(^|\n)` captures the start or a new-line character. http://regex101.com/r/gL7lH7/2

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)? It's all explained there, and a quick search would have found it.

Answer (score 4):

`(?:` is a non-capturing group

```
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
    ^                        the beginning of the string
   |                        OR
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
  )                        end of grouping
```

Have a look at [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/gL7lH7/1)

Read more about [Capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

> If you do not need the group to capture its match, you can optimize this regular expression into `(?:Value)`. The question mark and the colon after the opening parenthesis are the syntax that creates a non-capturing group.

In other words

```
(?:^|\n) Non-capturing group

 1st Alternative: ^
    ^ assert position at start of the string
 2nd Alternative: \n
    \n matches a fine-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

`(?:)` called non-capturing group which does only the matching operation and it won't capture anything.

```
>>> s = "sample text sample text\nsample text sample text"
>>> print s
sample text sample text
sample text sample text
>>> import re
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?:^|\n)', s, re.M) // In this re.findall function prints the matched characters(ie, two starts and a newline character).
>>> m
['', '\n', '']
>>> m = re.findall(r'(^|\n)', s, re.M) // In this re.findall function prints the captured characters.
>>> m
['', '\n', '']
```